# Getting conversion error with SQL Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 CASE WHEN Items.SerialNumber = -1 THEN Items.Aux1
 ELSE Items.SerialNumber
 END AS 'CheckNo'
```

This isn't working. I'm getting a converting varchar to int error. I am confused because if I ran this as a where query it works. I'm only getting the error in the case statement and don't see why.

Comment: What are the data types for `SerialNumber` and `Aux1` columns? Your `CASE` statement expects to return data of **one** type. So if `SerialNumber` and `Aux1` are different data types i.e. `SerialNumber` = `varchar` and `Aux1` = `int` then that is your problem.

Comment: What are the types of the columns involved here?  Can you show the "working" example as well?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: A column can only return one data type.  So if Items.Aux1 or items.serial number don't have the same data type (or precision), the system can't do what you're asking.  you'd have to cast/convert to change one of the two to varchar from int!

Comment: Aux1 is a varchar. SerialNumber is an int. How can I get past that. This is super frustrating lol. I am using SQL Server 2008. When I said working I just meant that if I set it equal to -1 I wasn't getting an error. The comment saying that my datatypes are different is more than likely my issue however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181765.aspx) `case statement`

> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.

`INT` has **higher precedence** than `varchar` so all the when expression will be implicitly converted to `INT`. To know more about datatype precedence *[check here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms190309.aspx)*

To avoid the **implicit** integer conversion, Convert the `INT` to `Varchar` in `when` expression

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Items.SerialNumber = -1 THEN Items.Aux1
         ELSE Cast(Items.SerialNumber AS VARCHAR(100))
       END AS 'CheckNo'
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up using a convert on the SerialNumber. I feel super slow now. Thanks all for your help with this.